# Using min(, [, key]) with multiple arguments in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to use `min(, [, key])` to find the nearest value from the current time `current_time` in 2 objects `left_data` and `right_data` which capture the 100 data points before and after the `current_time`.

```
            left_data= df.loc[i-100:i-1, 'Timestamp']
            right_data= df.loc[i+1:i+100, 'Timestamp']
```

The code I used looks like:

```
            data = min(left_data, right_data , key=lambda x: abs(x - current_time))
```

and it caught error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

In the doc it states that

```
The key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for list.sort()
```

Is it because I used 2 arguments instead of 1? How can I have 2 arguments for min(, [, key]) to work?

---

Edit:
`df` looks like:

```
    Timestamp                value    
0   2000-01-10 17:32:05.090 27.5  
1   2000-01-10 17:32:11.090 29.0
2   2000-01-10 17:32:15.090 31.0
3   2000-01-10 17:32:17.090 32.5
4   2000-01-10 17:32:19.090 34.0
5   2000-01-10 17:32:21.090 36.0
6   2000-01-10 17:32:23.090 37.5
7   2000-01-10 17:32:25.160 38.5
8   2000-01-10 17:32:27.160 39.5
9   2000-01-10 17:32:31.160 41.0
```

Comment: So you want to find the minimum point from _200_ data points? What you did is to find smaller series out of 2

Comment: I can't understand what should be compared to which. Could you show an example of what the dataframe might look like (you don't need 100 data points, but enough to make the example clear) and what the corresponding output should be?

Comment: @Chris Yeah so should I use `left_data.values` and `right_data .values`? It returned `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timestamp'`

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to reproduce? All I can say now is that you need to concat `left_data` and `right_data` into one (e.g. `np.stack`) and find the minimum **inside** that concatenated object.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel please see edited question.

Comment: @Chris yeah I just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `numpy.hstack`:

```
i = 5
current_time = df.loc[i, 'Timestamp']
left_data= df.loc[i-100:i-1, 'Timestamp']
right_data= df.loc[i+1:i+100, 'Timestamp'] 

min(left_data.append(right_data) , key=lambda x: abs(x - current_time))
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2000-01-10 17:32:19.090000')
```

If you want values:

```
i = 5
current_time = df.loc[i, "Timestamp"]
left_data= df.loc[i-100:i-1]
right_data= df.loc[i+1:i+100] 

min(left_data.append(right_data).to_numpy() , key=lambda x: abs(x[0] - current_time))[1]
```

Output:

```
34.0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer it works! But the datatime returned looks like `2000-01-10T17:32:51.160000000` which is of different format than `2000-01-10 17:59:36.120`. Do you know what format that is?

Comment: @nilsinelabore I've updated to get the original format. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I needed! Thank you:)

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm just wondering if there's a way to find the corresponding `value` of the same row for each `min(left_data.append(right_data) , key=lambda x: abs(x - current_time))`? I'm thinking about `zip` but I'm not sure if that's the best way.

Comment: @nilsinelabore You mean the corresponding index?

Comment: I mean the corresponding `Value` to that `Timestamp`. I'm thinking about using `iterrows()` now, any thoughts?

Comment: @nilsinelabore I've updated my answer. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for the update I just tested the code but it returned `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

Comment: Sorry I realised that there might be some miscommunication. By value in value column in the dataframe `df`. As I ran the code it caught error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'value'.`

Comment: @nilsinelabore I see no error. Please check that the updated code uses `dataframe` (there's no column selection in `df.loc[i-100:i-1]`). Your error is also slightly miss leading. The `values` at the end is not referring to the column name, but to make the dataframe a numpy array, let me make some change. If it doesn't work, let's move onto the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228552/discussion-between-nilsinelabore-and-chris).